# Weird error when linking static class with friend function

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, friend

I am having a lot of troubles with my C++ code but I can't understand why.

I am developing a static library libmylib.a that contains myclass.h and myclass.cpp.

The problem I am having is like this:

```
// myclass.h
class myClass{
   public:
      myclass();
      myclass(a,b);

     // some methods.

   private:
    int a ;
    int b ;
};
```

In myclass.cpp I define the constructors methods etc etc and everything works fine:
I am able to use the library in my main.cpp code.

I then added a friend function:

```
// myclass.h
class myClass{
   public:
      myclass();
      myclass(a,b);
      friend void foo() ;

     // some methods.

   private:
    int a ;
    int b ;
};
```

I define the foo function in myclass.cpp like this

```
// myclass.cpp
void foo(){
  cout << "In foo function " ;
}
```

The problem is that if I try to use foo() in main.cpp I get a compile error that states:

```
//main.cpp
#include "myclass.h" // foo() is declared here!

foo() ;
```

> main.cpp:62:6: error: ‘foo’ was not declared in this scope

Now I really can't understand where the problem is.
I notice that after adding the friend function it seems that the linker doesn't use mylib anymore, but I can't understand why. Moreover it is strange, because if I comment foo() in main.cpp myclass and its methods can be used without problems.

What am I doing wrong? I spent two hours trying to figure out, but really can't understand!!!

**Solution: following the advice in the answer:**

```
// myclass.h
void foo() ; // the function has to be declared outside the class

class myClass{
   public:
      myclass();
      myclass(a,b);
      friend void foo() ; // but here you have to specify that 
                          // is a friend of the class!
     // some methods.

   private:
    int a ;
    int b ;
};
```

Comment: Have you forward declared `foo()` function ? Or is `foo()` function defined before the point of calling ?

Comment: Yes I have. It is in myclass.h

Comment: @LucaCerone is it declared **outside** the class? Or just as a friend?

Comment: Ok. Is it a typo that you haven't ended your class definition with a `;` ?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore it is declared as in the example

Comment: @Mahesh yes sorry, it is a typo.

Comment: @LucaCerone so, in short, **it isn't declared**...

Comment: Try the second option from my answer. A declaration and naming it a friend are different.

Comment: Yes now I understand that it is not declared.. but before I thought it was :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a linker error, it is a compiler error. The compiler is telling you that it does not know how to call function `foo`, because it lacks its definition or declaration.

Declaring a function as a friend is no substitute for a proper declaration. When you say `foo` is a friend, you do not also introduce `foo` into a scope. In a sense, friendship declaration is a private detail of your class invisible from the outside.

In order to use a function in C++ you need to declare it first. This is usually done through a header file corresponding to the implementation file, but you can do it simply like this:

void foo();

If `foo` is defined in the same file as `main`, you can move `foo` ahead of the `main` to fix the problem (seeing a function definition prior to first use is OK with the compiler).

Comment: As I explained in the question, foo() is declared as a friend function in myclass.h. The definition is given in myclass.cpp.

Comment: @LucaCerone friendship declaration is a private detail of your class invisible from the outside. You need to properly declare your function. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks this worked! I'll edit the test to show the solution for the specific example!

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared `foo` before using it:

```
#include "header_where_foo_is_declared.h"
int main()
{
   foo();
}
```

or

```
void foo();
int main()
{
   foo();
}
```

???

Comment: Yes I did.. I explained the the declaration are done in myclass.h

Comment: @LucaCerone is it declared outside the class? Or just as a friend?